# Function and bounded derivatives

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, terminology

Let $f\in C^\infty([a,b])$ such as for all $x\in [a,b]$, the sequence $(f^{(n)}(x))_{n\geq 0}$ is bounded.
Show that there exists $C\geq 0$ such as for all $x\in [a,b]$ and for all n≥0, $|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq C$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: 9 months after, has no one been able to produce a proof?